# Angular router useFactory function not always called

Tags: angular, trace, race-condition, angular-router

In Angular 15, I have created an Angular Routing module that builds a list of routes dynamically according to the code below. For whatever reason, the useFactory specified provider function is only called sometimes when navigating to this route resulting in the child routes not being accessible and a redirect occurring back to the default page.

The code includes console log printouts and I can see that when the route list setup is successful, I get the console log print out indicating that the routes were created. At that point, all routes are accessible without issues. Conversely, there is no similar console log when the routing is having problems and multiple attempts to navigate to the routes repeatedly fail with redirect.

I am guessing that there is a race condition within Angular caused by the delayed loading of the dynamic components but that is just a guess. Any suggestions on how to resolve the issue of the useFactory method only being called sometimes?

Enabling trace routing has not helped and only serves to highlight that the child routes have not been instantiated. No Angular errors are printed in the console log either to indicate that something might have failed.

```
import { ApplicationContextService } from '../applicationContext.service';
import { HexagonSetupComponent } from './shapeSetup/hexagonSetup.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTES, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ShapeSetupComponent } from './ShapeSetup.component';
import { ShapeSetupDataService } from './ShapeSetupData.service';
import { SquareSetupComponent } from './shapeSetup/squareSetup.component';
import { TriangleSetupComponent } from './shapeSetup/triangleSetup.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild( [] )],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [{
        provide: ROUTES,
        useFactory: (context: ApplicationContextService) => {
            let childRouteList = [];
            let routeList: Routes =
            [{
                path: '', component: ShapeSetupComponent,
                children: childRouteList
            }];

            if (context.installation == null)
            {
                return routeList;
            }

            let componentType: any;
            let shapeTextId: string;
            for (let shape of context.shapeList)
            {
                switch(shape.shapeType)
                {
                    case "triangle": componentType = TriangleSetupComponent; break;
                    case "square": componentType = SquareSetupComponent; break;
                    case "hexagon": componentType = HexagonSetupComponent; break;
                }
                shapeTextId = shape.label.toLowerCase().replace( /\s/g, "" );
                childRouteList.push( { path: shapeTextId, resolve: { data: ShapeSetupDataService }, component: componentType } );
            }

            console.log( "Child routes created" );

            return routeList;
        },
        deps: [ApplicationContextService],
        multi: true
    }]
})
export class ShapeSetupRoutingModule { }
```

Is there a way to force the loading of the providers?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a general answer but in my case, I had to add a router subscription at the application level in order to detect my dynamically added (and lingering) routes and reroute before they were called.

```
    constructor( private router: Router )
{
    router.events.subscribe( (event: Event) =>
    {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart)
        {
            // Show loading indicator
            if ((!this.isLoggedIn()) && (event.url != '/') && (event.url != '/login'))
            {
                router.navigate( [''], { replaceUrl:true } );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What this did was to avoid accessing the lingering dynamic routes that should no longer be available on reload to avoid the problem.